# How to change Audio CMSampleBuffer format(change the mSampleRate 44100.000000 to 8000.000000.)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using AVCaptureAudioDataOutput for audio output and getting result form

```
          - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutputdidOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

but i want to change the sampleBuffer audio format (CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription). please help me if it is possible.want to change mSampleRate .

```
Currently getting
mediaSpecific: {ASBD: {mSampleRate: 44100.000000mFormatID: 'lpcm'mFormatFlags: 0xcmBytesPerPacket: 2mFramesPerPacket: 1mBytesPerFrame: 2mChannelsPerFrame: 1mBitsPerChannel: 16 }
```

**but i need to change the mSampleRate 44100.000000 to 8000.000000.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationAudioSettings_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009937

You have to setup the AVAudioRecorder.

Hope, that helps!

Comment: Thanks...! I just want downsample its mSampleRate from 44100 to 8000.